# Load viewstub in the landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm showing a transparent layout as viewstub in my application.

```
    ViewStub newview = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.newstb);    
mButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (shouldShowInstructions()) {

                    // Shows the instructions view and returns
                    newview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mIsShowingIntsructions = true;
                    return;
                } else {

                    // some execution
                }
            }
        });
```

Its showing properly on the button click. Here is the xml:

```
     </LinearLayout>

     <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/newstb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/new_overlay"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when user rotate the screen i want to get the xml from layout-land.Name of the both xmls are new_overlay.xml. I thought it will be done automatically as the property of android. But no luck. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Manifest and check if you have set the property

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

for that specific activity. If that´s the case, the layout-land xml will not be load automatically.

In this case you have two options:

- Handle layout changes in onConfigurationChanged()
- Or remove those options from the manifest (their use is not recommended anyway, if you trust the many blogs about this topic), and handle orientation changes by yourself using onSaveInstanceState(). This way the layout-land xml will automatically be recognize.